# In PyGitHub, how do you set set_labels?

Tags: python, pygithub

I am building a GitHub action that,

1. gets existing issue labels
2. adds correct priority labels
3. sets all labels

The relevant part is,

```
def required_labels(current_labels, required_priority):
    if current_labels is None:
        return [required_priority]
    labels_out = []
    for label in current_labels:
        if label not in possible_priorities:
            labels_out.append(label)
            continue
        if label != required_priority:
            continue
    labels_out.append(required_priority)
    return labels_out

out_labels = required_labels(existing_labels, body_priority_label)
issue.set_labels(out_labels)
```

The [set_labels docs](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Issue.html?highlight=set_labels#github.Issue.Issue.set_labels) say that it requires

> list of `github.Label.Label` or strings

I, therefore, expected that a list of strings, `labels_out`, would work, however, `set_labels` returns

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/Issue.py", line 545, in set_labels
    assert all(
AssertionError: (['enhancement', 'P2'],)
```

I also tried making a union of this list but saw no change.

```
set().union(out_labels)
```

I also tried using the repo label object.

```
for label in labels_names:
    labels_out.append(repo.get_label(name=label).name)
```

This returned,

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/github/Repository.py", line 2631, in get_label
    assert isinstance(name, str), name
AssertionError: ['enhancement', 'P2']
```

When I provide many strings to `set_labels`, it works as expected.

```
    issue.set_labels("Separate", "Strings", "Work", "As", "Expected")
```

Clearly, one will not know how many labels an issue might have. How should I provide the required labels to `set_labels`?

Comment: Unpack `out_labels` as `issue.set_labels(*out_labels)`, like the documentation shows.

Comment: @Nelewout I missed that in the docs, where does it say that?

Comment: @Nelewout TIL that unpacking lists is a thing. Thanks!. Put it into an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Issue.html?highlight=set_labels#github.Issue.Issue.set_labels) describes the following function signature:

```
set_labels(*labels)
```

The 'star' in front of `labels` in the function signature indicates a variadic argument which takes zero, one, or more labels.

So, you can unpack your list before passing it to `set_labels`, as follows:

```
issue.set_labels(*out_labels)
```

You can read more about arguments and argument unpacking in Sections 4.7.3 and 4.7.4 of the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).